# How to Grab exact pixel by pixel picture seen on surface view when using the Camera

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I am using the Camera on Android.  The SurfaceHolder is used to show the preview screen.  I need to have the exact, pixel by pixel picture seen on the SurfaceView.  How do I do that ?

I tried getting the dimensions of the Surface view when

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
            int format, int width,
            int height) {}
```

Is called, then use those measurements to transform the taken picture from

```
public void onPictureTaken( byte[] data, Camera camera ) { }
```

This works, but only on some devices.  Other devices distort the picture.

Answer (score 0):

EASY:

Create a 
    byte[] buffer;

```
camera.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);
```

You also want to set the size of the buffer:

```
int height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
int width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
int bitsPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat());

buffer = new byte[width * height * bitsPerPixel];
```